# Specify my own select dropdown for page size

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to have a select menu that is outside of the datatables grid that I can use to control the page size.

I am aware that I can move the page size dropdown anywhere within the grid using the `dom` option and setting `>l`. However, I want to use a dropdown that is outside of the grid, so I cannot use this option.

I am assuming I either have to handle the change event on my own dropdown, then do something to set the page size property and then call `.draw()`.

Or even better, when initializing the datatable, tell it which select dropdown to use for page size and have it handle the change.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to create a new dropdown (length menu) from scracth, just move the length menu to whereever you want it to be positioned using **[`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)** and [**`appendTo()`**](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/). In dataTables, the length menu always have the id `<datatable-id>_length`, so do this after you have initialised the dataTable :

```js
var dataTable = $("#example").DataTable();
...
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#example_length").detach().appendTo('#container')
});
```

where `#container` is where you want the length menu to be placed outside the grid.
See demo (1.10.x) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rjo8hfsu/**